# pywinauto - ImportError: DLL load failed for win32ui

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I frequently get this error (9/10 times) when running my scripts that use pywinauto

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python3.4.5\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 45, in <module>
    import win32ui
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Sometimes there's no error but most of the times it errors out and so its taking me longer to test my scripts.

***import win32ui*** on its own does not give any errors at all. Does anyone know how to get this resolved?

Python 3.4.5
Windows10
PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5

Comment: I suspect that you have both 32-bit and 64-bit installations of Python and it works when you load  `pywinauto` from the Python of one bitness but not the other. You have to install *all* modules with C extensions (.pyd files) with bitness that matches the Python interpreter.

Comment: I've tried importing it in the same Pycharm project where it fails when being imported via pywinauto, so I can rule out bitness of Python here.

Comment: This looks like there is something that PyCharm's import wrapper is not handling as expected. Two things to try: (1) If you have imports of the form `import a,b,c` for modules that have anything to do with PythonWin then put the imports in separate statements. (2) Try putting `import win32ui` ahead of `import pywinauto` in your code. If the first import is successful then PyCharm's wrapper should do nothing and with any luck will then not fail. If that doesn't help I suggest you seek help on a JetBrains forum since the problem seems to be specifically related the PyCharm import hook manager.